# SSRS Search box that filters the data

Tags: reporting-services

How can I add a search box to a SSRS Report that interactively filters two datasets without having to click the view report?

For example lets say I start typing 001...now I am expecting to see all records that contain 001 I know I can do this with a standard parameter but I woiuld like to filter the data as I type, and potentially remove the view report button.

Comment: Please show us what you did so far (code examples). Also use [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to format and formulate your question.

Comment: My data is sensitive.

Comment: @Flat_Cap_Hat you can always use dummy data...

Comment: How could anyone review/ improve your code if you don't share it? SO is **not** a coding delivery service, but a Q/A forum. If you don't want to share your code, nobody will write it for you and your question will not get answered...

Comment: Not sure you can filter the returned results from within SSRS
You may need to bolt on a .Net Web App

Comment: Within the confines of SSRS you cannot do this.